# Swift override generic swift

Tags: swift, generics, mvvm

I am trying to implement generic for MVVM Swift. I have two base class, an protocol for generic class. The special in here is inheritance. I tried for three hour but I can't fix it :(.

```
protocol ObjectProtocol {
    var id: Int { get set }
    var name: String { get set }
}

class BaseViewModel<T: ObjectProtocol> {

    var objects: [T] = []

    init(){

    }
}

protocol ListViewControllerType {

    associatedtype T: ObjectProtocol
    associatedtype ViewModelType: BaseViewModel<T>
    var viewModel: ViewModelType! { get set }


    func showError(error: String)
}

extension ListViewControllerType  {

    func showError(error: String) {
        print(error)
    }
}

class Consult: ObjectProtocol {
    var id: Int = 1
    var name: String = "Consult"
}

class ConsultViewModel<T: Consult>: BaseViewModel<Consult> {

}

class ConsultViewController: ListViewControllerType {
    var viewModel: ConsultViewModel<Consult>!
}
```

But I get error in `var viewModel: ConsultViewModel<Consult>!`

This is error: `Type 'ConsultViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ListViewControllerType'`

Someone have experience with generic and inheritance can help me please.
Thank you so much.

Comment: try to remove all implementation of  `ConsultViewController` and let Xcode generate the stubs

Comment: Xcode only generate variable but It don't generate type
`class ConsultViewController: ListViewControllerType {
    typealias T = Consult
    
    typealias ViewModelType = ConsultViewModel<T>!
}`
But it still not work

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/davidpasztor/8811bb6a803062fda58bea364e4c861e) gist for more information on the error. It seems like the actual error is `'ConsultViewController.ViewModelType' (aka 'ConsultViewModel<Consult>') does not inherit from 'BaseViewModel<T>'` after you add the typealias. It seems like the compiler cannot infer `T` as `Consult` for `BaseViewModel<T>`. In a generic function, where the compiler can figure out that `T` is the same for both `ConsultViewModel` and `BaseViewModel`, the inheritance is actually determined. Haven't figured out a solution though.

Comment: I still can't fix it.

Comment: I tried to covert from protocol to inheritance but it still don't work. You can see gist <script https://gist.github.com/Hoangtaiki/1266d78d5c027814e850a0c79b7daebf

Comment: You can use something like this: https://gist.github.com/mukeshydv/80c412cb0fc56d6679ed3a7326f0ec85

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this:

```
class BaseViewModel {
}

class TemplateViewModel<T: ObjectProtocol>: BaseViewModel {
    var objects: [T] = []
    init(){
    }
}
```